# MySQL order of 'quests' based on a second table columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is a list of 'quests' and a second table that is a list of "quest path" (when one quest ends, I know which quest is granted next.). The quests are not stored in sequential order so I'm attempting to order them based on when one ends and the other begins.

Quests

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | title        | missionID    |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | A Middle     | quest234     |
|  2 | The Start    | quest567     |
|  3 | A Middle 2   | quest987     |
|  4 | The End      | quest654     |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

QuestPath

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | grants       | ends         |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | quest234     | quest567     |
|  2 | quest987     | quest234     |
|  3 | quest654     | quest987     |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

This is what i'm looking for, "The Start" is not in the QuestPath table under granted so it's assumed to be the first mission

Results

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | grants       | missionID    |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | The Start    | quest567     |
|  2 | A Middle     | quest234     |
|  3 | A Middle 2   | quest987     |
|  4 | The End      | quest654     |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: "when one ends and the other begins" how do you know when on ends and the other begins?  Are the ids on the quest table sequential?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm getting it. You don't actually want the "order" you want the "hierarchy", which is best served by a hierarchical query. Coming soon to a MySQL server near you.

Comment: Before MySQL v8, there was basically no support for hierarchical data or recursive queries.  Alas, that makes this almost impossible to do without a cursor.

Comment: They were added to MariaDB in 10.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct Quests.* 
from Quests
left join
QuestPath on Quests.missionID = QuestPath.grants
order by QuestPath.id
```

The `id` column (2,1,3,4) is the original `id` from `Quests` not the sequence number or row numbers on the output.